# App crashing when running without a debugger (or in release mode)

Tags: ios, iphone, maui

When running the app with the debugger attached the app works just fine (debug version). Now disconnect the debugger and start the app manually (no debugger attached) and it crashes...

Even when compiling in release mode the app crashes. The following crash report is captured using:

1. Navigate to Privacy&Security > Analytics & Improvements > Analytics Data
2. Select the Claro app crash from the list. This will start with the name of the app and contain the time of the crash.
3. Tap on the crash and you will the text of the crash log. Select all the text, select ‘Copy’ and then paste it

Initial crash report didn't show much, after which i checked the App Center (Microsoft) issues where i noticed the following:

> SIGABRT SIGABRT: Position 73:41. StaticResource not found for key
> tt_SfListView

Eventhough the tt_SfListView is defined in the app.xaml the system does crash on this element.

```
<Style TargetType="SfListView:SfListView" x:Key="tt_SfListView">
 <Setter Property="SelectionBackground" Value="#2C4135"/>
 <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="#2C4135"/>
 <Setter Property="Grid.BackgroundColor" Value="#2C4135"/>
</Style>
```

== crash report ==

```
{"app_name":"TotalTrackMaui","timestamp":"2023-03-02 20:35:11.00 +0100","app_version":"1.0","slice_uuid":"e8d13002-9a54-306d-a8e0-8f27cbc7c618","build_version":"1.1.6","platform":2,"bundleID":"eu.cande.TotalTrack","share_with_app_devs":1,"is_first_party":0,"bug_type":"309","os_version":"iPhone OS 16.3.1 (20D67)","roots_installed":0,"name":"TotalTrackMaui","incident_id":"B607CF4B-9DFA-4D46-85C3-5426D15A21B6"}
{
  "uptime" : 990000,
  "procRole" : "Foreground",
  "version" : 2,
  "userID" : 501,
  "deployVersion" : 210,
  "modelCode" : "iPhone14,2",
  "coalitionID" : 6580,
  "osVersion" : {
    "isEmbedded" : true,
    "train" : "iPhone OS 16.3.1",
    "releaseType" : "User",
    "build" : "20D67"
  },
  "captureTime" : "2023-03-02 20:35:10.7743 +0100",
  "incident" : "B607CF4B-9DFA-4D46-85C3-5426D15A21B6",
  "pid" : 22988,
  "cpuType" : "ARM-64",
  "roots_installed" : 0,
  "bug_type" : "309",
  "procLaunch" : "2023-03-02 20:35:04.7937 +0100",
  "procStartAbsTime" : 23831124394850,
  "procExitAbsTime" : 23831267706115,
  "procName" : "TotalTrackMaui",
  "procPath" : "\/private\/var\/containers\/Bundle\/Application\/BCC0749E-CD93-4B1B-A034-9D2DD88C1E96\/TotalTrackMaui.app\/TotalTrackMaui",
  "bundleInfo" : {"CFBundleShortVersionString":"1.0","CFBundleVersion":"1.1.6","CFBundleIdentifier":"eu.cande.TotalTrack"},
  "storeInfo" : {"deviceIdentifierForVendor":"3466D252-A449-4DCF-A736-C47F11B57025","thirdParty":true},
  "parentProc" : "launchd",
  "parentPid" : 1,
  "coalitionName" : "eu.cande.TotalTrack",
  "crashReporterKey" : "0a7e79dd6cc97154d8d26e288a2657cd6f9a13df",
  "wasUnlockedSinceBoot" : 1,
  "isLocked" : 0,
  "throttleTimeout" : 2147483647,
  "basebandVersion" : "2.40.01",
  "exception" : {"codes":"0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000","rawCodes":[0,0],"type":"EXC_CRASH","signal":"SIGABRT"},
  "asi" : {"libsystem_c.dylib":["abort() called"]},
  "faultingThread" : 0,
  "threads" : [{"triggered":true,"id":11030279,"threadState":{"x":[{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":800},{"value":4395452160},{"value":3107},{"value":18446744069414593792},{"value":13252501095028755438},{"value":13252501085865410606},{"value":312},{"value":68},{"value":4423257088},{"value":4437696187},{"value":224},{"value":2147483648},{"value":328},{"value":9174420416,"symbolLocation":0,"symbol":"_main_thread"},{"value":0},{"value":6},{"value":259},{"value":9174420640,"symbolLocation":224,"symbol":"_main_thread"},{"value":4431349760},{"value":1},{"value":10766165424},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":6170115233},{"value":10740024528}],"flavor":"ARM_THREAD_STATE64","lr":{"value":9039098284},"cpsr":{"value":1073745920},"fp":{"value":6170113328},"sp":{"value":6170113296},"esr":{"value":1442840704,"description":" Address size fault"},"pc":{"value":8762914420,"matchesCrashFrame":1},"far":{"value":5036068896}},"name":"tid_103","queue":"com.apple.main-thread","frames":[{"imageOffset":30324,"symbol":"__pthread_kill","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":29100,"symbol":"pthread_kill","symbolLocation":268,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":134284,"symbol":"abort","symbolLocation":180,"imageIndex":2},{"imageOffset":76792152,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":78732736,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":79826452,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":76830460,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":80294648,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":88416,"symbol":"start","symbolLocation":2528,"imageIndex":4}]},{"id":11030280,"frames":[{"imageOffset":2960,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":0,"imageIndex":1}]},{"id":11030282,"name":"SGen worker","frames":[{"imageOffset":5756,"symbol":"__psynch_cvwait","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":32876,"symbol":"_pthread_cond_wait","symbolLocation":1232,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":79737468,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":5836,"symbol":"_pthread_start","symbolLocation":148,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":2980,"symbol":"thread_start","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":1}]},{"id":11030283,"name":"Finalizer","frames":[{"imageOffset":3364,"symbol":"semaphore_wait_trap","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":79267360,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":79115140,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":79114764,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":5836,"symbol":"_pthread_start","symbolLocation":148,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":2980,"symbol":"thread_start","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":1}]},{"id":11030284,"frames":[{"imageOffset":2960,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":0,"imageIndex":1}]},{"id":11030285,"name":"tid_2d03","frames":[{"imageOffset":2960,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":0,"imageIndex":1}]},{"id":11030286,"frames":[{"imageOffset":2960,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":0,"imageIndex":1}]},{"id":11030287,"name":"tid_4003","frames":[{"imageOffset":2960,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":0,"imageIndex":1}]},{"id":11030288,"name":"com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread","frames":[{"imageOffset":3496,"symbol":"mach_msg2_trap","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":80412,"symbol":"mach_msg2_internal","symbolLocation":80,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":80988,"symbol":"mach_msg_overwrite","symbolLocation":388,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":4844,"symbol":"mach_msg","symbolLocation":24,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":502468,"symbol":"__CFRunLoopServiceMachPort","symbolLocation":160,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":507144,"symbol":"__CFRunLoopRun","symbolLocation":1232,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":528048,"symbol":"CFRunLoopRunSpecific","symbolLocation":612,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":270420,"symbol":"-[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:]","symbolLocation":212,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":270140,"symbol":"-[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:]","symbolLocation":64,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":5072548,"symbol":"-[UIEventFetcher threadMain]","symbolLocation":436,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":374040,"symbol":"__NSThread__start__","symbolLocation":716,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":5836,"symbol":"_pthread_start","symbolLocation":148,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":2980,"symbol":"thread_start","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":1}]},{"id":11030290,"name":".NET Timer","frames":[{"imageOffset":5756,"symbol":"__psynch_cvwait","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":32920,"symbol":"_pthread_cond_wait","symbolLocation":1276,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":77163672,"symbol":"SystemNative_LowLevelMonitor_TimedWait","symbolLocation":104,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":9841612,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":63808292,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":65674652,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":79801860,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":79010088,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":79115388,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":79114764,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":5836,"symbol":"_pthread_start","symbolLocation":148,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":2980,"symbol":"thread_start","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":1}]},{"id":11030291,"name":"JavaScriptCore libpas scavenger","frames":[{"imageOffset":5756,"symbol":"__psynch_cvwait","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":32876,"symbol":"_pthread_cond_wait","symbolLocation":1232,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":1011772,"symbol":"scavenger_thread_main","symbolLocation":1164,"imageIndex":8},{"imageOffset":5836,"symbol":"_pthread_start","symbolLocation":148,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":2980,"symbol":"thread_start","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":1}]},{"id":11030367,"name":".NET ThreadPool Worker","frames":[{"imageOffset":5756,"symbol":"__psynch_cvwait","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":32876,"symbol":"_pthread_cond_wait","symbolLocation":1232,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":79426980,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":79445044,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":8465600,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":65528252,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":65516684,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":79801860,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":79010088,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":79115388,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":79114764,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":5836,"symbol":"_pthread_start","symbolLocation":148,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":2980,"symbol":"thread_start","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":1}]},{"id":11030368,"name":".NET ThreadPool Gate","frames":[{"imageOffset":5756,"symbol":"__psynch_cvwait","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":32920,"symbol":"_pthread_cond_wait","symbolLocation":1276,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":77163672,"symbol":"SystemNative_LowLevelMonitor_TimedWait","symbolLocation":104,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":9841612,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":63808292,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":65674652,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":65516684,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":79801860,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":79010088,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":79115388,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":79114764,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":5836,"symbol":"_pthread_start","symbolLocation":148,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":2980,"symbol":"thread_start","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":1}]},{"id":11030369,"name":".NET ThreadPool Worker","frames":[{"imageOffset":5756,"symbol":"__psynch_cvwait","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":32876,"symbol":"_pthread_cond_wait","symbolLocation":1232,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":79426980,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":79445044,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":8465600,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":65528252,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":65516684,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":79801860,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":79010088,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":79115388,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":79114764,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":5836,"symbol":"_pthread_start","symbolLocation":148,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":2980,"symbol":"thread_start","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":1}]},{"id":11030372,"name":"com.apple.coremedia.rootQueue.47","frames":[{"imageOffset":3388,"symbol":"semaphore_timedwait_trap","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":17824,"symbol":"_dispatch_sema4_timedwait","symbolLocation":64,"imageIndex":9},{"imageOffset":19360,"symbol":"_dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow","symbolLocation":76,"imageIndex":9},{"imageOffset":88128,"symbol":"_dispatch_worker_thread","symbolLocation":324,"imageIndex":9},{"imageOffset":5836,"symbol":"_pthread_start","symbolLocation":148,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":2980,"symbol":"thread_start","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":1}]},{"id":11030373,"name":"com.apple.coremedia.rootQueue.47","frames":[{"imageOffset":3388,"symbol":"semaphore_timedwait_trap","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":17824,"symbol":"_dispatch_sema4_timedwait","symbolLocation":64,"imageIndex":9},{"imageOffset":19360,"symbol":"_dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow","symbolLocation":76,"imageIndex":9},{"imageOffset":88128,"symbol":"_dispatch_worker_thread","symbolLocation":324,"imageIndex":9},{"imageOffset":5836,"symbol":"_pthread_start","symbolLocation":148,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":2980,"symbol":"thread_start","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":1}]},{"id":11030383,"frames":[{"imageOffset":2960,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":0,"imageIndex":1}]},{"id":11030404,"name":"com.apple.coremedia.rootQueue.47","frames":[{"imageOffset":3388,"symbol":"semaphore_timedwait_trap","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":17824,"symbol":"_dispatch_sema4_timedwait","symbolLocation":64,"imageIndex":9},{"imageOffset":19360,"symbol":"_dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow","symbolLocation":76,"imageIndex":9},{"imageOffset":88128,"symbol":"_dispatch_worker_thread","symbolLocation":324,"imageIndex":9},{"imageOffset":5836,"symbol":"_pthread_start","symbolLocation":148,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":2980,"symbol":"thread_start","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":1}]},{"id":11030428,"name":"com.apple.coremedia.rootQueue.47","frames":[{"imageOffset":3388,"symbol":"semaphore_timedwait_trap","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":17824,"symbol":"_dispatch_sema4_timedwait","symbolLocation":64,"imageIndex":9},{"imageOffset":19360,"symbol":"_dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow","symbolLocation":76,"imageIndex":9},{"imageOffset":88128,"symbol":"_dispatch_worker_thread","symbolLocation":324,"imageIndex":9},{"imageOffset":5836,"symbol":"_pthread_start","symbolLocation":148,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":2980,"symbol":"thread_start","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":1}]},{"id":11030446,"name":".NET ThreadPool Worker","frames":[{"imageOffset":5756,"symbol":"__psynch_cvwait","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":32876,"symbol":"_pthread_cond_wait","symbolLocation":1232,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":79426980,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":79445044,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":8465600,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":65528252,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":65516684,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":79801860,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":79010088,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":79115388,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":79114764,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":5836,"symbol":"_pthread_start","symbolLocation":148,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":2980,"symbol":"thread_start","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":1}]},{"id":11030447,"name":".NET ThreadPool Worker","frames":[{"imageOffset":5756,"symbol":"__psynch_cvwait","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":32876,"symbol":"_pthread_cond_wait","symbolLocation":1232,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":79426980,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":79445044,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":8465600,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":65528252,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":65516684,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":79801860,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":79010088,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":79115388,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":79114764,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":5836,"symbol":"_pthread_start","symbolLocation":148,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":2980,"symbol":"thread_start","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":1}]}],
  "usedImages" : [
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64e",
    "base" : 8762884096,
    "size" : 229356,
    "uuid" : "c76e6bed-4635-30c6-8f19-fb829bbe1ae1",
    "path" : "\/usr\/lib\/system\/libsystem_kernel.dylib",
    "name" : "libsystem_kernel.dylib"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64e",
    "base" : 9039069184,
    "size" : 49152,
    "uuid" : "45ac734e-6649-3ee2-a096-3fd66441ab78",
    "path" : "\/usr\/lib\/system\/libsystem_pthread.dylib",
    "name" : "libsystem_pthread.dylib"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64e",
    "base" : 7851966464,
    "size" : 524280,
    "uuid" : "3cd8c9e0-25fd-3b29-8507-74cdffe7f16c",
    "path" : "\/usr\/lib\/system\/libsystem_c.dylib",
    "name" : "libsystem_c.dylib"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64",
    "base" : 4296769536,
    "size" : 84443136,
    "uuid" : "e8d13002-9a54-306d-a8e0-8f27cbc7c618",
    "path" : "\/private\/var\/containers\/Bundle\/Application\/BCC0749E-CD93-4B1B-A034-9D2DD88C1E96\/TotalTrackMaui.app\/TotalTrackMaui",
    "name" : "TotalTrackMaui"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64e",
    "base" : 8240984064,
    "size" : 536724,
    "uuid" : "4b042f28-0d14-30ec-a1de-3dbb10866ad7",
    "path" : "\/usr\/lib\/dyld",
    "name" : "dyld"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64e",
    "base" : 7727820800,
    "size" : 4087808,
    "uuid" : "42ccfc7b-ff32-3d25-8f01-ccb2ad843a8b",
    "path" : "\/System\/Library\/Frameworks\/CoreFoundation.framework\/CoreFoundation",
    "name" : "CoreFoundation"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64e",
    "base" : 7630741504,
    "size" : 9740288,
    "uuid" : "e5f615c7-cc5e-3656-8600-41c767812a35",
    "path" : "\/System\/Library\/Frameworks\/Foundation.framework\/Foundation",
    "name" : "Foundation"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64e",
    "base" : 7763296256,
    "size" : 25116672,
    "uuid" : "cf21ad9c-efbf-3961-a7c0-54bd30cefea9",
    "path" : "\/System\/Library\/PrivateFrameworks\/UIKitCore.framework\/UIKitCore",
    "name" : "UIKitCore"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64e",
    "base" : 8053800960,
    "size" : 21753856,
    "uuid" : "400bebf5-2e9d-30cc-a5dc-eb81436379de",
    "path" : "\/System\/Library\/Frameworks\/JavaScriptCore.framework\/JavaScriptCore",
    "name" : "JavaScriptCore"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64e",
    "base" : 7851675648,
    "size" : 290816,
    "uuid" : "ded4d0a5-1420-32ae-83a6-c31d938a1c9a",
    "path" : "\/usr\/lib\/system\/libdispatch.dylib",
    "name" : "libdispatch.dylib"
  }
],
  "sharedCache" : {
  "base" : 7611203584,
  "size" : 2945138688,
  "uuid" : "213ec2e7-4556-3c2c-9a30-cdf930db9f0d"
},
  "vmSummary" : "ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=1.1G resident=0K(0%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=1.1G(100%)\nWritable regions: Total=851.9M written=0K(0%) resident=0K(0%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=851.9M(100%)\n\n                                VIRTUAL   REGION \nREGION TYPE                        SIZE    COUNT (non-coalesced) \n===========                     =======  ======= \nActivity Tracing                   256K        1 \nCG raster data                      64K        2 \nColorSync                           80K        5 \nCoreAnimation                     4128K       29 \nFoundation                          16K        1 \nImage IO                           224K       14 \nKernel Alloc Once                   32K        1 \nMALLOC                           608.9M      212 \nMALLOC guard page                  192K       12 \nSQLite page cache                  256K        2 \nSTACK GUARD                        336K       21 \nStack                             20.4M       21 \nVM_ALLOCATE                       23.3M       64 \nWebKit Malloc                    192.1M        6 \n__AUTH                            3352K      433 \n__AUTH_CONST                      28.0M      670 \n__CTF                               756        1 \n__DATA                            13.3M      659 \n__DATA_CONST                      33.4M      676 \n__DATA_DIRTY                      3471K      585 \n__FONT_DATA                        2352        1 \n__LINKEDIT                       308.5M        3 \n__OBJC_CONST                      6528K      464 \n__OBJC_RO                         78.9M        1 \n__OBJC_RW                         2440K        1 \n__TEXT                           769.6M      685 \ndyld private memory                256K        1 \nlibnetwork                         640K       16 \nmapped file                      232.1M      849 \nshared memory                       48K        3 \n===========                     =======  ======= \nTOTAL                              2.3G     5439 \n",
  "legacyInfo" : {
  "threadTriggered" : {
    "name" : "tid_103",
    "queue" : "com.apple.main-thread"
  }
},
  "trialInfo" : {
  "rollouts" : [
    {
      "rolloutId" : "60da5e84ab0ca017dace9abf",
      "factorPackIds" : {

      },
      "deploymentId" : 240000008
    },
    {
      "rolloutId" : "61675b89201f677a9a4cbd65",
      "factorPackIds" : {
        "HEALTH_FEATURE_AVAILABILITY" : "638e768d75b0720ff1f8c4f3"
      },
      "deploymentId" : 240000051
    }
  ],
  "experiments" : [
    {
      "treatmentId" : "4a50e2ff-e2f7-45ad-8edf-ac503433ac9a",
      "experimentId" : "62e47e747613a16313832faa",
      "deploymentId" : 400000018
    },
    {
      "treatmentId" : "a2c66376-6910-4142-b340-3476dd2ce1bf",
      "experimentId" : "621923057b59736391be1571",
      "deploymentId" : 400000011
    }
  ]
}
}
```

After finishing debugging and testing, the app was pushed to a physical phone for further testing. That moment we noticed that post the face-id (login page) or using a username and password on the login page the app crashes.

Comment: Do you have any exception handling in your code, or any crash reporting tools?

Comment: `TargetType="SfListView:SfListView"` - near the top of app.xaml file, do you have a line `xmlns:SfListView ...`?  That would be required for that target. If so, add that line of xaml to  your question's code.

Comment: 1) To be sure this isnt a symptom of some other error, remove references to tt_SfListView from login page. You'll likely get some different error. 2) I've never seen a style cause problem only when no debugger. Having username and password lead to crash sounds like a completely different problem. Wrap `try..catch` around all code involved in processing username/password.

Comment: Yes, we use AppCenter (Microsoft) and found the issue.

Answer (score 1):

During debug sessions styles that are undefined in the app.xaml file will not cause an application crash or error. Only when the debugger is not attached or a release version is build, this error is manifesting itself.

This is clearly a Maui issue that need to be addressed by Microsoft.

Check the code for any styles defined on controls and validate that they are also included in the app.xaml file.

In my case the tt_SfListView was defined though uncommented during development testing. This resulted in controls still having **Style="{StaticResource tt_SfListView}"** in the control parameters:

```
         <SfListView:SfListView
                        x:Name="listViewAvailableCartridges"
                        SelectionMode="Single"
                        SelectionGesture="Tap"
                        AllowSwiping="True"
                        SwipeStarting="listViewAvailableCartridges_SwipeStarted"
                        SwipeEnded="listViewAvailableCartridges_SwipeEnded"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding ammoInventory.AvailableCartridgesCollection}"
                        SelectionChanged="listViewAvailableCartridges_SelectionChanged"
                        Style="{StaticResource tt_SfListView}">


        <!-- <Style TargetType="SfListView:SfListView" x:Key="tt_SfListView">
            <Setter Property="SelectionBackground" Value="#2C4135"/>
            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="#2C4135"/>
            <Setter Property="Grid.BackgroundColor" Value="#2C4135"/>
        </Style> -->
```

Once the exclusion was removed the app ran without problems.

Comment: Reproducing the error is possible. Also checked the error, warnings and messages post a rebuild of the project. It is not marking any potential issue ... Luckily we had AppCenter already installed and configured, otherwise this was impossible to track down.

Comment: It doesn't have to be a `Style`. I've just had the same issue with an image `StaticResource` named incorrectly. Searching for `XamlParseException` in the Android LogCat output should find `StaticResource` problems and any more general XAML faults that (for whatever reason) are only throwing when the debugger isn't attached.